# Browser hangs after AJAX complete (waiting response?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest

Not really expecting to get answer but struggling with this 2 days now and have no idea whats going on.

So here what I have done:

Uploading file via AJAX and immediately starting processing it in backend.

```
$.ajax({
  type : "post",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  url : formAction,
  data : formData
});
```

In backend I writing session where storing current progress like 500 of 10000...

Then I calling another AJAX to check status from session, I calling this funcion every 1 second till responsve returns 'done'.

Looks legit to me, but problem is that after backend proccessing done, and first XHR changing status from 'pending' to 200 browsers freeze, looks like something is blocking it, like another request or somehing. chekc screens bellow.

[image: starting to process imported file]

So it's done, check is stopped, status is changed to 200, nothing happening but browsers freeze, tried Chrome, Firefox...Browser suggesting me to kill process, but if I wait some time it will refresh.

[image: Done]

**UPDATE**

So i lie a little bit, I tried again do same but without ajax and saw similar issue, after backend processing complete, browser waiting response (spinning backwards)...So that is what cousin hanging.

Here is my backend it's Laravel

```
foreach ($chunks as $rows)
        {
            $current_chunk++;

            if ( $current_chunk < $all_chunks ) {
                Session::put(['import_progress'=>'Importing ' . $current_chunk * 150 . ' of ' . $all_results]);
                Session::save();
            } elseif ( $current_chunk >= $all_chunks ) {
                Session::put(['import_progress'=>'done']);
            }

            foreach ($rows as $row)
            {
                // transakcija start
                DB::transaction(function() use ($row) {

                    $code = $row[0];
                    $gender = $row[1];
                    $brand_name = filter_var($row[2],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $category = $row[3];
                    $subcategory = $row[4];
                    $condition = $row[5];
                    $details = $row[6];
                    $composition = $row[7];
                    $materials = $row[8];
                    $colors = $row[9];
                    $patterns = $row[10];
                    $country = $row[11];
                    $size = $row[12];
                    $m_a = $row[13];
                    $m_b = $row[14];
                    $m_c = $row[15];
                    $m_d = $row[16];
                    $m_e = $row[17];
                    $m_f = $row[18];
                    $m_g = $row[19];

                    $product = new Product();
                    $product->code = $code;
                    $product->gender = $gender;
                    $product->size = $country . ' | ' . $size;
                    $product->condition = $condition;
                    $product->measurement_a = $m_a;
                    $product->measurement_b = $m_b;
                    $product->measurement_c = $m_c;
                    $product->measurement_d = $m_d;
                    $product->measurement_e = $m_e;
                    $product->measurement_f = $m_f;
                    $product->measurement_g = $m_g;
                    $product->save();

                    if ( empty($code) ) {
                        $bad_prods[] = $product->id;
                    }

                    if ( !empty( $brand_name ) ) {
                        $brand = Brand::firstOrCreate(['brand_name'=>$brand_name]);
                        $product_b = new ProductBrand();
                        $product_b->brand_id = $brand->id;
                        $product_b->product_id = $product->id;
                        $product_b->save();
                    }

                    if ( !empty( $materials ) ) {
                        $materials_exp = explode(',',$materials);

                        foreach ($materials_exp as $material) {
                            $material = Material::firstOrCreate(['material_name'=>trim($material)]);
                            $product_m = new ProductMaterial();
                            $product_m->material_id = $material->id;
                            $product_m->product_id = $product->id;
                            $product_m->save();
                        }
                    }

                    if ( !empty( $patterns ) ) {
                        $patterns_exp = explode('/',$patterns);
                        foreach ($patterns_exp as $pattern) {
                            $pattern = Pattern::firstOrCreate(['pattern_name'=>trim($pattern)]);
                            $product_p = new ProductPattern();
                            $product_p->pattern_id = $pattern->id;
                            $product_p->product_id = $product->id;
                            $product_p->save();
                        }
                    }

                    if ( !empty( $colors ) ) {
                        $colors_exp = explode('/',$colors);
                        foreach ($colors_exp as $color) {
                            $color = Color::firstOrCreate(['color_name'=>trim($color)]);
                            $product_c = new ProductColor();
                            $product_c->color_id = $color->id;
                            $product_c->product_id = $product->id;
                            $product_c->save();
                        }
                    }

                    $product_t = new ProductTranslation();
                    $product_t->product_id = $product->id;
                    $product_t->product_title = $brand_name;
                    $product_t->product_description = '<p>'.$details.'</p><p>'.$composition.'</p>';
                    $product_t->save();

                }); // end transakcija
            }
        }

        Session::put(['import_progress'=>'done']);
        Session::put(['bad_prods'=>$bad_prods]);

        return redirect()->route('admin.import');
```

And here I'm checking status

```
public function status()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => Session::get('import_progress'),
            'bad_prods' => Session::get('bad_prods')
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Have **SetTimeout()** or **SetInterval()** Anywhere in rest of the code ? 
Post the part where you are calling the function after regular interval.

Comment: I have, but same happening without checking status, so it's not an issue...

Comment: Post the snippet where you are refreshing/checking status

Comment: Added cheking status method, very simple just getting data from the session wich i set in proccessing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When processing is done I put simple exit(); at the end of processing Controller...Not sure why this works and any other return statement doesn't.